# List Items Middle Vertically Aligned

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following HTML and CSS that creates a list, where the list items have a min-height set.  I would like for the contents of the list items to be vertically aligned in the middle instead of the top if there is not enough content to fill the entire height.  How the heck do I pull this off?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                width : 300px;
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            li {
                min-height : 45px;
                vertical-align : middle;
                border-bottom : 1px black solid;
            }
        </style>
    <head>
    <body>
        <ul>    
            <li>Testing testing 1234</li>
            <li>Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234</li>
            <li>Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234</li>
            <li>Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234</li>
            <li>Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234 Testing testing 1234</li>
       </ul>
 </body>
```

Which gives me the following:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you add a `<div>` inside the `<li>` and make the following changes to the CSS, it seems to work:

```
li {
    min-height : 45px;
    border-bottom : 1px black solid;
}
li div {
    height:45px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align : middle;
}
```

See it live here-- works in IE8 and FF4: http://jsfiddle.net/RrVBh/

Comment: @Steve: Be aware, no support for this CSS in IE < 8. Otherwise this is a great solution.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know, if IE7 support is needed, you may have to just cave and slap an actual table inside each `<li>`, since `display:table-cell` isn't supported. It's ugly, but hey, IE is ugly.

Comment: Is there any reason why I would just not use a table at that point?

Comment: If you need IE<8 compatibility, then no, not really. I find myself resorting to tables more than I'd like to admit, just because IE6/7 compatibility is a user requirement. Just mutter an incantation, make sure no one's looking, and enter the dark side. Making the sign of the cross is optional.

Answer (score 5):

Ahh, good ol' [vertical align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html). The easiest way is to set `line-height: 45px;` but this only works when you have one line of content and will force any additional lines to overflow.

Otherwise, you could use `display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` as demonstrated in the above link.

Comment: I don't see how either of the two methods mentioned in that article will work. One assumes a fixed height, which mine is not, and the other method assumes one line, which my layout is not.

Comment: That's the point. You can't really vertically align text outside of a table layout / CSS3. Your only other option would be look into the new [flexible box model layout](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) for CSS3.

Comment: CSS Grid also has vertical alignment capabilities: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/