# Vertically Align <a> tag inside of a list

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically align an anchor tag within a list item, i have managed to horizontally align it so far. See code below and check jsfiddle for demo.

HTML

```
        <div id="header-top"> 
        <div id="header-top-middle">
            <ul>
                <li><a data-icon="&#xe602;" a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a data-icon="&#xe600;" a href="#">222222222</a></li>
                <li><a data-icon="&#xe601;" a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a data-icon="&#xe603;" a href="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#header-top {
    height:30px;
    background-color:#303030;
    width: auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDDDDD; 
}
#header-top-middle {
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:30px;
}
#header-top-middle ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
#header-top-middle ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#header-top-middle ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRadK/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: table` for your list:

```
#header-top-middle ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: table;
}
```

as well as `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` for your link inside list item:

```
#header-top-middle ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRadK/9/)**

Comment: Yes, that's it. But, since OP has limited width... i thought that line-height is enough...

Comment: Line-height was not enough, when i added it to ul li a, it did nothing. It works on ur JSfiddle demo, but integrated with the rest of my site, it wasent working.

Answer (score 3):

Add line-height:30px to a:

http://jsfiddle.net/hRadK/1/

```
#header-top-middle ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Comment: How about the text is two line instead of one line?

Comment: @Felix, harder. :) Please post solution for it, i had some javascript+css+additional html fixes long time ago... maybe pure css solution is possible nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

In the link, Chris deals with centering an element whose width and height are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header-top-middle ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    //display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hRadK/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219515/926710) answer of wrapping your hyperlinks in a `div` and applying the vertical alignment on the `div`. The only other amendment you will need to make is then to remove the block display of hyperlinks you currently have defined.

```
#header-top-middle ul li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /* display: block;  - remove this rule */
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRadK/10/)